# if div with id has certain text remove other div

Tags: php, javascript, css, if-statement

if div with id has certain text remove other div.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
var text = $('#div_with_dynamic_text').text();
var comparingText = 'THE_TEXT'
if(text == comparingText){
 $('#OTHER_DIV).css('display','none'); 
 }; 
</script>

<div id="div_with_dynamic_text">THE_TEXT</div>
<div id="OTHER_DIV"> some other div which needs to hide if certain text</div>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing single quote in `$('#OTHER_DIV')` - is that the issue or is that just a typo in the code in your question?

Comment: On a side note, using something like prettify or other JS validation makes it pretty obvious.

Comment: A side note: The script tag should come below the div in present code, else it will not be able to find the div's, as it loads earlier in the dom than the div's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You Missed the single Quote. It will work great.

```
<script language="javascript"> 
var text = $('#div_with_dynamic_text').text();
var comparingText = 'THE_TEXT'
if(text == comparingText){
 $('#OTHER_DIV').css('display','none'); 
 }; 
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! what a fast answer. thanx again!

Answer (score 1):

Single quote is missing :
Change this:

```
$('#OTHER_DIV).css('display','none');
```

To:

```
$('#OTHER_DIV').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler approach

```
if($("div:contains('THE_TEXT')").length>0){
$('#OTHER_DIV').css('display','none');
}
```